# Can an account prefix in a NXT clone blockchain be longer than three characters?

Tags: alternatives, nxt

I'm getting errors setting up the account prefix after cloning NXT with the Nxt Blockchain Creation Kit. Are there restrictions on how many characters?

Answer (score 3):

No, currently the account prefix (`ACCOUNT_PREFIX` constant) must be exactly 3 characters. This could be fixed in future.